# How to clear a Text Box when changing something in a Combo box?

Tags: vb.net

I'm quite new to coding and I wanted to know how do I get the Text box to clear what's in it when I choose another option in a Combo box, I'm using Visual Basic.
I tried searching for answers myself but came up with nothing, and tried searching for something to help myself but considering I'm new I don't really know where to look.

Comment: What have you tried? Consider: what event(s) fire when something in a `ComboBox` changes? Which property of the `TextBox` to you want to change?

Comment: What UI technology are you using?  Winforms?  WPF?  If WPF, you'd normally handle this through data binding and properties on your viewmodel object, and it would be pretty trivial unless you're doing something unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ComboBox` and go to its **Event** properties located at the bottom-right corner after selecting it. Then you should have found something `SelectedIndexChanged`, just simply double-click on it and write the following:

```
myTextBox.Text = "" ' replace myTextBox with your required TextBox
```

Alternatively:

```
myTextBox.Clear()
```

That's it.